# Ordenar campo ou notificações de data expirada, banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Nada sei sobre banco de dados, estou usando um no Visual Studio (o SQL padrão chamado "Banco de dados baseado em serviços"), já integrei ele ao formulário e fiz até os campos de consultas.

Mas tem um campo de uma das tabelas que seria de data, essa data é como um 'empréstimo', e ela expira (daqui uma semana, como exemplo).

Então daí vem a dúvida (pesquisei e não encontrei nada sobre isso).

**A dúvida é:**

Como ordeno uma tabela desse banco de dados pelo campo de `data`, mostrando os registros do campo da `data` mais antiga a mais nova?

Outra dúvida (essa é mais avançada), mas a primeira já basta pra mim (sou humilde kk), é tipo, esse campo de `data`, como eu falei, é como empréstimo, então queria saber, tomando exemplo o registro:

```
"Nome: José", "Data do empréstimo: 23/06/2015"
```

Nessa tabela, como estimulei a data de vencimento é uma semana, o vencimento seria hoje, então como pegar esse registro do banco de dados e armazenar em uma variável (para ser exibido em outro formulário)?

O outro campo:

```
"Nome: João", "Data do empréstimo: 24/06/2015"
```

O vencimento seria amanhã, então ele amanhã ele iria enviar esse registro ao outro formulário automaticamente, como se fosse uma notificação de vencimento.

Comment: Como está a estrutura da sua tabela, esse prazo é que tipo? E como você está fazendo pra chamar as consultas via c#?

Comment: A estrutura pede nome, contato, item emprestado.. O prazo é tipo `datetime`. A consulta fiz conforme esse vídeo -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qt0z2ySimV8 (porque realmente sei nada disso, praticando é que se aprende)

Comment: entao vc tem a coluna de data emprestimo e prazo? no prazo você salva tipo data emprestimo + 1 semana?

Comment: Sim, exatamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a principio apenas ordenar as datas você pode usar `order by`.

Ex: 
`SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC`

`desc`para decrescente e `asc` para ascendente, quanto pegar a data que expiram, na função `Load` do formulário, vc pode chamar uma função para fazer isso, vc pode criar uma instrução `sql` para buscar isso no banco algo como:

Ex: `SELECT * FROM usuarios where dataemprestimo > datalimite`

assim vc teria todas os registros que a ultrapassaram a data limite, detalhe, para funcionar essa `query` vc precisa de um campo que fique armazenado a data limite para o usuário devolver o produto, coisa simples de fazer no `insert`e na programação na hora do cadastrar.

OBS: se você me der o nome das tabelas eu coloco aqui a função.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   notificarUsuarios()
End Sub

 Private Sub notificarUsuarios()
 se quiser apenas armazenar 1 data, mais vc pode jogar em um datagrid
     Dim nomeDoUsuario As String = nomeDataSet.Tables("usuarios").Rows(0)("usuario")
     Dim dataVencida As String = nomeDataSet.Tables("usuarios").Rows(0)("dataexpira")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Os nomes são os mesmos rs `usuarios` e o nome da tabela, e o `dataemprestimo` e `datalimite` os campos `datetime` né? Só o `datalimite` que ta `dataexpira` no meu (isso eu já aprendi de tanto olhar nos códigos gerados pelo Visual kk)

Comment: só uma obs, vc precisa colocar a instrução `sql` no `dataset` que você ira utilizar, para isso clique com o direito no `DataSet`, va em `Configure...` e add essa query: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE dataemprestimo > dataexpira ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC` fica a critério seu chamar todos os campos com `*` ou apenas os campos `nomeusuario` e `datalimite`,

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer a data mais ANTIGA e não a mais NOVA, você quer *ascendente* e não *descendente*.

```
SELECT * FROM Emprestimo
ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC
```

### [SqlFiddle Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18120/1/0)

Sobre seu segundo problema, você pode utilizar a variável do Sql Server pra pegar o dia e hora atual `GETDATE()`.

Dessa forma em uma tabela as vencidas fica:

```
SELECT * FROM Emprestimo
WHERE datalimite <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC
```

E na tabela as que não venceram ainda fica:

```
SELECT * FROM Emprestimo
WHERE datalimite > GETDATE()
ORDER BY dataemprestimo ASC
```

Comment: Daí esses comandos são inseridos no arquivo da tabela né? '-'

Comment: No video que você mandou é nos 0:35 onde ele adiciona a consulta